# Open conjecture in number theory without a good heuristic?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, open-problem

For most open conjectures in number theory , there are good heuristics that they are true : Examples include the Goldbach conjecture, the Collatz conjecture , the Riemann hypothesis and the twin prime conjecture.

> Are there conjectures in number theory which are not disproved, but there is also no good heuristic that they are true ?

Comment: Maybe you mean "experimental evidence" ?

Comment: May be I think even the results on odd perfect numbers  also somewhat belong here. Since it is unknown whether there exists such a number, but there are several results as to the bounds on such numbers

Comment: @vidyarthi In fact, although many mathematicians are convinced that no odd perfect number exists, apart from several restrictions no convincing heuristic is currently known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Hardy-Littlewood Conjectures](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hardy-LittlewoodConjectures.html) do not have a "good heuristics" and are known to be contradictory to each other. The first one is known as strong twin prime conjecture, and the [second one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) states that
$$
\pi(x+y)\le \pi(x)+\pi(y)
$$
for all $x,y\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

How about the infinitude of the number of Fermat primes?

Fermat primes are prime numbers of the form
\[
2^{2^{n}} + 1.
\]

They are just too large to check their primality even for moderately small values of $n$.

Comment: In this case, there is a strong heuristic for the set being finite, using the same approach as for things like Goldbach and twin prime as mentioned in the original question.